# PHP: Unexpected 'StringLiteral'. Expected ','

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, backend

I get this error notice in the VS code `Unexpected 'StringLiteral'. Expected ','` with the PHP code below. Please help me understand what is wrong in it. I see this error with the line beginning with Click to..

```
while ($dbh->next_record()) {
    $tracker_info = json_decode($dbh->Record['tracker_info'], TRUE);
    inform_sl_operations("PO$dbh->Record['po_number'] needs Follow Up. Due: $dbh->Record['alert'] \n" 
        . " Click to <a href="'search_results.php?po_number=$dbh->Record['po_number']'">view order</a>,"
        . " service@pmm.com", "PO $dbh->Record['po_number'] needs Follow Up");
}
```

Comment: Just never put variables in strings. Concatenate them using `.`: `"PO" . $dbh->Record['po_number'] . "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `"` inside quotes, like:

```
$string = "href="example.com"";
```

Is wrong and needs to be escaped, like:

```
$string = "href=\"example.com\"";
```

---

Another possible mistake, don't do:

```
$string = "$dbh->Record['po_number']";
```

Store in variable then use, like:

```
$po_number = $dbh->Record['po_number'];
$string = " ... $po_number ... ";
```

---

Try something like:

```php
while ($dbh->next_record()) {
    $tracker_info = json_decode($dbh->Record['tracker_info'], TRUE);

    $num = $dbh->Record['po_number'];
    $alert = $dbh->Record['alert'];

    inform_sl_operations("PO $num needs Follow Up. Due: $alert \n" 
        . " Click to <a href=\"search_results.php?po_number=$num\">view order</a>,"
        . " service@pmm.com", "PO $num needs Follow Up");
}
```

Comment: @CodeForGood Seems that post has already a good answer; which was added just 15 minutes after your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes in the `href` attribute of the `<a>`

```
"<a href=\".......\">"
```

Comment: could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked